# Function cannot be deleted as it is being provisioned

Tags: serverless, nuclio

I am trying to deploy a serverless function with nuclio, but for some reason it failed to build. Now when I do nuctl get function. It just states that the function is in build state. How can I delete it?

P.s I am trying the SAM integration with CVAT by running the
./deploy_cpu.sh pytorch/facebookresearch/sam/nuclio/

I tried looking up ways to force delete the function, but there's no such thing

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE

I managed to do this using the nuclio's dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete this function by nucleo by run this comand:

```
nuctl delete function <function-name>
```

It works well with CVAT for me.

Run this command to get all function running by nucleo:

```
nuctl get function --namespace nuclio
```

We get this responce:

```
NAMESPACE  | NAME                           | PROJECT | STATE    | REPLICAS 
 nuclio    | pth-facebookresearch-sam-vit-h | cvat    | building | 1/1
```

run this command to delete `pth-facebookresearch-sam-vit-h`:

```
nuctl delete function pth-facebookresearch-sam-vit-h
```

Then run this command get all function running by nucleo again:

```
nuctl get function --namespace nuclio
```

And we see that there is no functions running by nucleo.

If it doesn't help you can do it by nucleo UI like in this answer in this issue [link](https://github.com/nuclio/nuclio/issues/3013#issuecomment-1709715345).

Answer (score 1):

If you get a delete error, do the following

```
nuctl delete function <function-name> --platform local --force
```

Comment: --force flag did it for me